# Best Practice For Consistent REST Status On Success/Failure (Using LoopBack)

Tags: loopbackjs

We're using LoopBack (by StrongLoop) for our REST framework. What is the best practice for determining success or failure?

A successful result simply returns the the data (in JSON). An unsuccessful result returns readyState, responseText, status and statusText. **It would be really nice if the successful result also returned a status so we have a consistent method of checking for success/failure.** However, we don't want to mix status codes in with our data either.

```
function write(authkey, type, url, data, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        error: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the HTTP status code instead of depending on the results of the callback (ie. HTTP 200 = OK, 401 = Not Found, etc)

Comment: The problem is that there is no status code (i.e. 200) for a successful result. The 'status' field does not exist.

Comment: So, use (for example) the JQuery 'statusCode' on the AJAX call rather than relying on callback results?  Makes sense.